# Equality between two subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra

If $S,T,V$ are subspaces of a vector space E over a field $\mathbb{K}$, such that $T\subset V$, prove that $T+(S{\cap}V)=(T+S){\cap}V$.

I have problems to test the double containment.

Comment: What kind of problems? Be specific.

Comment: I would not know whether to use extension base or some other method for equality?

Comment: Pick an element of one, explain why it's an element of the other. For example, pick an element of $T+(S\cap V)$. It looks like $t+s$ where $t\in T$ and $s\in S\cap V$. Can you explain why it's an element of $(T+S)\cap V$? Notice the latter is equivalent to saying why $t+s$ is in both $T+S$ and $V$...

Comment: @arctictern Thanks for your contribution!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Suppose that $x\in T+(S\cap V)\to x=t+u, t\in T, u\in S\cap V$. Now, $x\in T+ S $ because $x=t+u$ and $x=t+u\in V$ because $T\subset V\to t\in V\to t+u\in V$.

The reciprocal is similar.